# Mobile App for Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, api, sharepoint, rest, mobile

I'm trying to develop a mobile app that will integrate with Sharepoint 2010 so that my clients can make approvals and stuff from a mobile device. (I'm hoping to build a HTML5/Android Native app that will call webservices and get the job done)

I looked it up and there is a RESTful API for Sharepoint that I think I can use with the ECMAScript library. Can I use this same REST API to view pending approvals, to approve/reject, etc or is the functionality limited to viewing data?

Sorry but i'm a newbie to Sharpoint. Could someone throw a little light on whether I have the right idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**For my needs I am using custom SOAP Web Services to do what I want in SharePoint side.** Unfortunately, I have no experience with the built-in services, may be it is enough for your needs, but I don't think so. But you can start your investigation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx

Creation of custom Web Services is simple and it can give you great possibilities.

**On the mobile part I am using [Cordova (PhoneGap)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html) to create mobile application (based on Html+JS). For WebService invokation I am using code like this:**

```
var url=server+"/_layouts/CustomWebServices/MyCustomWebService.asmx";
var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
req.onreadystatechange= function(){
    if(req.readyState != 4) return;
    if(req.status != 200) {
        if (onerror)
            onerror('status: '+req.status+req.responseCode+req.responseText);
        return;
    }
    callback();
};
var soapBodyDoc=mkXML(soapBody);
req.open("POST",url,true);
req.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://mysite/'+soapAction);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+auth);
req.setRequestHeader('Expect', '100-continue');
req.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
req.send(soapBodyDoc);
```

As you can see I am using [Basic authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Maybe it is not the best approach, but I am a newbie too :). I can't remember for the moment, what I exactly did to allow Basic authentication, but if you couldn't find this information let me know, I'll try to remember.

To create UI you can use [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It is very useful.

If you have additional questions - let me know.

Comment: Hey @Puhan thanks for the reply. Developing the app is fine. I use JqueryMobile and Phonegap as well. It's just that I'm unsure of how much I can do using the Rest interface. Do they let a third part app approve/reject stuff in the workflow for a document? Can I run updates/inserts through the webservices?