# How to download and upload file from SharePoint Server in Java?

Tags: java, sharepoint

I am trying to write a simple example code with the help of this [java-sharepoint-library](https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/)

library but still i am not able to design simple program.

Comment: the sample code to download file is already in the "API exmaple" section in the link you provided. for upload file, i dont think it is supported by the library.

Comment: Yes i did not get lots of classes file in jars

Answer (score 0):

For development used information - https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/
Everything is well described there.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class LoginManagerSharePoint {
    private final String sts = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf";
    private final String loginContextPath = "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";
    //private final String contextInfoPath = "/_api/contextinfo";
    private final String sharepointContext = "xxxxxxx";
    private final String reqXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
            "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" " +
            "xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" " +
            "xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
            "<s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue" +
            "</a:Action><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>" +
            "</a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>" +
            "<o:Security s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" " +
            "xmlns:o=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">" +
            "<o:UsernameToken><o:Username>[username]</o:Username><o:Password>[password]</o:Password>" +
            "</o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken " +
            "xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\">" +
            "<wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\">" +
            "<a:EndpointReference><a:Address>[endpoint]</a:Address></a:EndpointReference>" +
            "</wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey" +
            "</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue" +
            "</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>" +
            "</t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
    private String generateSAML() {
        String saml = reqXML
                .replace("[username]", "username");
        saml = saml.replace("[password]", "password");
        saml = saml.replace("[endpoint]", String.format("https://%s.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0", sharepointContext));
        return saml;
    }

    public String getCookie() {
        String token;
        try {
            token = requestToken();
            String cookie = submitToken(token);
            //System.out.println(cookie);
            return cookie;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String requestToken() throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

        String saml = generateSAML();

        URL u = new URL(sts);
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294274/mobile-app-for-sharepoint/12295224#12295224
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        wout.write(saml);

        wout.flush();
        wout.close();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        int c;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) (c));
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        String token = extractToken(result);
        //System.out.println(token);
        return token;
    }

    private String extractToken(String result) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(result)));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
        String token = xp.evaluate("//BinarySecurityToken/text()", document.getDocumentElement());
        //handle error  S:Fault:
        //http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/df862099-d9a1-40a4-b92e-a107af5d4ca2
        //System.out.println(token);
        return token;
    }

    private String submitToken(String token) throws IOException {
        // http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch03s05.html
        String url = String.format("https://%s.sharepoint.com%s", sharepointContext, loginContextPath);
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294274/mobile-app-for-sharepoint/12295224#12295224
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        wout.write(token);

        wout.flush();
        wout.close();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        //http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/GetHeaders.html
        String setCookieRtFa = null;
        String setCookieFedAuth = null;

        for (int i=0; ; i++) {
            String headerName = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
            String headerValue = connection.getHeaderField(i);
            //System.out.println("header: " + headerName + " : " + headerValue);
            if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
                // No more headers
                break;
            }
            if (headerName == null) {
                // The header value contains the server's HTTP version
            }

            if (headerName != null) {
                if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                    if (setCookieRtFa == null) {
                        setCookieRtFa = headerValue;
                    } else {
                        int t = 0;
                        if (headerValue.equals("RpsContextCookie=; path=/"))   t = 1;

                        if (t == 0) {
                            setCookieFedAuth = headerValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        String cookieContainer = setCookieRtFa.split("\\;")[0] + ";" + setCookieFedAuth.split("\\;")[0];

        in.close();

        return cookieContainer;
    }
}

   LoginManagerSharePoint loginManagerSharePoint = new LoginManagerSharePoint();
    String cookieContainer = loginManagerSharePoint.getCookie();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_FILE);
        httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", cookieContainer);
        httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks