# Downloading files from Sharepoint URL

Tags: java, excel, sharepoint, download

I am new to `Sharepoint`. I have a couple of files that I need to download and I am trying to achieve this using `CURL/Wget` or `Java`.

**The files that I need to download are present as lists on the `sharepoint`. I'll need to select all the individual items and then click on `Export to Excel` in the `List` panel to download the files as Excel sheets. Is it at all possible to download these files?**

I tried doing CURL and Wget with the URL but the whole html content is getting downloaded.

I searched for any Java libraries available for connecting to sharepoint and came across this: https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-sharepoint-library/

I tried running this sample code using the above library:

```
NtlmAuthenticator credentials = new NtlmAuthenticator("sharepoint2.xxxxxxx.com", "username", "password");

      try {
           SPSite instance = new SPSite(new URL("https://sharepoint2.xxxxxxx.com/sites/PIR/"), credentials, true);              
           List<SPWeb> result = instance.getAllWebs();
           System.out.println(result);
           if ((result != null) && (result.size() > 1)) {
               SPWeb web = result.get(0);
               // Lists
               List<SPList> lists = web.getLists();
               assertNotNull(lists);
               if ((lists != null) && (lists.size() > 1)) {
                   // List items in list
                   SPList list = lists.get(0);
                   // List items in document library
                   list = lists.get(0);
                   List<SPListItem> items = list.getItems();
                   for (SPListItem item : items) {
                       File file = new File("c:\\" + item.getFile().getName());
                       item.getFile().saveBinary(file);
                   }
               }
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

when I run the above code, it fails at `List<SPWeb> result = instance.getAllWebs();` with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.korecky.sharepoint.WsContext.getWebsPort(WsContext.java:150)
    at org.korecky.sharepoint.SPSite.getAllWebs(SPSite.java:116)
    at access.main(access.java:20)
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. And I am clueless to try out any new ways of downloading the files.

I am open to trying out new ways instead of java. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the example code below:

```
NtlmAuthenticator credentials = new NtlmAuthenticator("DOMAIN", "username", "password"); 

// Connect to Sharepoint 
SPSite instance = new SPSite(new URL("https://www.server.com/"), credentials, null, true, SPVersion.SP2013); 
// Get root web instance 
SPWeb rootWeb = instance.getRootWeb();
```

Check the document from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/java-sharepoint-library/javadocs.zip

For Office 365, we can use **Office 365 SDKs for Java**.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not able to find the `NetworkCredentials` class. that's the reason why I tried using `NtlmAuthenticator` instead. Any idea what jar I should be adding for the `NetworkCredentials` class?

Comment: Check if the domain name is right. I modify the code in above and check whether the instance is null or not.

Comment: Still getting the same error, `NullPointerException` :( . Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Try to use Chilkat: https://www.example-code.com/java/sharepoint_download_file.asp

Answer (score 0):

For development used information - https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/
Everything is well described there.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class LoginManagerSharePoint {
    private final String sts = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf";
    private final String loginContextPath = "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";
    //private final String contextInfoPath = "/_api/contextinfo";
    private final String sharepointContext = "xxxxxxx";
    private final String reqXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
            "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" " +
            "xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" " +
            "xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
            "<s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue" +
            "</a:Action><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>" +
            "</a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>" +
            "<o:Security s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" " +
            "xmlns:o=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">" +
            "<o:UsernameToken><o:Username>[username]</o:Username><o:Password>[password]</o:Password>" +
            "</o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken " +
            "xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\">" +
            "<wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\">" +
            "<a:EndpointReference><a:Address>[endpoint]</a:Address></a:EndpointReference>" +
            "</wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey" +
            "</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue" +
            "</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>" +
            "</t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
    private String generateSAML() {
        String saml = reqXML
                .replace("[username]", "username");
        saml = saml.replace("[password]", "password");
        saml = saml.replace("[endpoint]", String.format("https://%s.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0", sharepointContext));
        return saml;
    }

    public String getCookie() {
        String token;
        try {
            token = requestToken();
            String cookie = submitToken(token);
            //System.out.println(cookie);
            return cookie;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String requestToken() throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

        String saml = generateSAML();

        URL u = new URL(sts);
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294274/mobile-app-for-sharepoint/12295224#12295224
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        wout.write(saml);

        wout.flush();
        wout.close();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        int c;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) (c));
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        String token = extractToken(result);
        //System.out.println(token);
        return token;
    }

    private String extractToken(String result) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(result)));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
        String token = xp.evaluate("//BinarySecurityToken/text()", document.getDocumentElement());
        //handle error  S:Fault:
        //http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/df862099-d9a1-40a4-b92e-a107af5d4ca2
        //System.out.println(token);
        return token;
    }

    private String submitToken(String token) throws IOException {
        // http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch03s05.html
        String url = String.format("https://%s.sharepoint.com%s", sharepointContext, loginContextPath);
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294274/mobile-app-for-sharepoint/12295224#12295224
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        wout.write(token);

        wout.flush();
        wout.close();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        //http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/GetHeaders.html
        String setCookieRtFa = null;
        String setCookieFedAuth = null;

        for (int i=0; ; i++) {
            String headerName = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
            String headerValue = connection.getHeaderField(i);
            //System.out.println("header: " + headerName + " : " + headerValue);
            if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
                // No more headers
                break;
            }
            if (headerName == null) {
                // The header value contains the server's HTTP version
            }

            if (headerName != null) {
                if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                    if (setCookieRtFa == null) {
                        setCookieRtFa = headerValue;
                    } else {
                        int t = 0;
                        if (headerValue.equals("RpsContextCookie=; path=/"))   t = 1;

                        if (t == 0) {
                            setCookieFedAuth = headerValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        String cookieContainer = setCookieRtFa.split("\\;")[0] + ";" + setCookieFedAuth.split("\\;")[0];

        in.close();

        return cookieContainer;
    }
 }

    LoginManagerSharePoint loginManagerSharePoint = new 
    LoginManagerSharePoint();
    String cookieContainer = loginManagerSharePoint.getCookie();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_FILE);
    httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", cookieContainer);
    httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.